# Typescript: Call constructor when passing class as an object

Tags: typescript

So I have a class that needs to take in another class as an option. I have the following

```
class MyClass
{
    interface IOptions
    {
        factory? : Function;
    }

    constructor(data: any, options: IOptions)
    {
        this._factory = new options.factory();
    }
}
```

`options.factory` can be passed to this a couple of different ways but it should be a class that can then be called with new.

I am trying to pass across the class like:

```
this._options.factory = MyOtherClass;
var myClass= new MyClass(data, this._options);
```

Where `MyOtherClass` is a class with a constructor.

The error in my IDE when I try `options.factory()` is

```
Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

Which makes sense, but how can I do this?

Comment: I'm not a typescript expert, but I believe the linked duplicate is what you are after. If I am wrong I will retract my close vote.

Comment: Usually it's good for code to constitute a [mcve] so others can tweak it.  Since I don't know what your types are supposed to be and the code is invalid (e.g., can't define an interface inside a class) I can only [guess](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkAOZgHsQDOyA3gFDLLwJi5QCeA-AFzIgQDuyAFAJTIC8APmRwQdANzIA9FOQJ8BMFACu1WsjB1MEUgF9SCADZwCRALJ0AwsdMlyyAPpUa9FqIn35hJapdcAJnBgcG5iADTIuNh4hCwY0Qp8ZBQUYAAWwAQAdE6ILnQCkQmEWc60BQysHEU4CqV55bzILABE7Gm4yADWILjsBC32+vpAA) what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SeanBright: that works for me. thanks